# Почему возникает ошибка и как сохранить елемент в массив в localStorage. Ошибка getItem

Tags: javascript, массивы, localstorage

Почему возникает ошибка и как сохранить елемент в массив в `localStorage`. Ошибка `getItem`.

```
var keepValue = document.getElementById('keep').value;

// Function for set id key for person date.
function IndefityKey(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
}

var key = IndefityKey(10000000000000000);

var blocky = {
  Key: key,
  Content: keepValue
};

// Get Array
var GetArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('KeyArray'));
// Push elem to array
GetArr.push(blocky);

// Update Array
localStorage.setItem('KeyArray', JSON.stringify(GetArr));
```

Comment: конкретнее что за ошибка

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var GetArr = [];
if (localStorage.getItem('KeyArray'))
  GetArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('KeyArray'));
// Push elem to array
GetArr.push(blocky);
```